# How to ALLOW caching when querystrings are used?

Tags: javascript, html, url, caching, query-string

I use querystrings to save page data for objects inside of the page. You can see it in action [here](http://showpony.heybard.com/) (if you click inside of some of the story objects, you'll see the querystring change).

But as I understand it, in general different querystrings on a webpage will result in the webpage being reloaded. I don't want that, because the querystring is just being used to save object data- it doesn't effect anything else on the webpage. All that happens is I change an object property in JavaScript based on my querystring; none of the files actually change.

Is there a way around the cache-breaking? Is there a way I can use querystrings in my webpage url and still use the cache? (so `example.com?var=val` will fetch `example.com`?)

I'm also open to messing around with using hashes instead, if that would be necessary.

Thanks!

Edit: this isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page), I'm not interested in modifying the URL while the user's on a webpage. I'm interested in not reloading a webpage's files when a new querystring is used.

So if a user visited `example.com` and then returns to `example.com?page=40`, I'd like to reload the relevant HTML page that was saved with `example.com`.

I did just realize that I had had a brain fart through; only the core page would be reloaded, I don't have to worry about all the connected scripts and stylesheets like I had been. So this wouldn't likely be that big of a deal. Still, I'm interested in if there are any answers or ideas.

Comment: _“I don't want that, because the querystring is just being used to save object data- it doesn't effect anything else on the webpage”_ - then you have simply chosen the wrong place to store your data to begin with. A different query string means a different URL - the browser _can not_ have that cached if it did not request it before already.

Comment: The reason for the different URL is for the data to be passed between users or saved in bookmarks. The object data I'm referring to is a bookmark. So if a user shares `examples.com?page=40" the person they're sharing the URL with will start on page 40 rather than page 1 or the last page. I do need data that can easily be shared between users like that, but was hoping to avoid caching for repeat users.